# Problem with blur in uploaded YouTube video

Tags: youtube

A video I uploaded to youtube has clips from various sources.  All the clips from one source (Source 1) show blurred results.  Clips from all the other sources looked fine.

All the clips are 1920x1080 and everything looks good when exported from Davinci Resolve.

I’ve tried uploading several times with the same result.  And I checked several hours after uploading to give youtube processing plenty of time.

Searching google suggested that differences between the specs of clips can cause trouble on YouTube, so I’ve now uploaded another version of the video using only clips from source 1.  (The Davinci project is set to the same resolution as all the clips)

All the footage is blurred on YouTube.

This all seems kind of impossible to me and I've never had a problem like it on other videos!  Can anyone help please?

Thanks
Andy

Answer (score 0):

My first questions would be:

- Is the exported clip interlaced? Maybe your video player can account for interlacing artifacts in a way that youtube does differently.
- Does the original clip, as used in the timeline, have a different frame rate that the others, or perhaps it is interlaced and others aren't? Maybe first transcoding it to match the others will help.

If the answer to both is no, I would start looking at the exported file. Does the blurring appear in youtube when other exported codecs are used, like H.264 versus VP9, AVC etc?

I hope that helps you find a solution.

Comment: Hi Wiley.

Thanks for helping.

In Clip Attributes/Field Dominance all the clips are set to Auto-progressive. I think that means they’re interlaced?

The problem clips are all 29.97 or 30fps but two clips that youtube handles well are also 29.97  (There are other clips at 25 but they’re ok on youtube too.)

Here’s one of my test uploads: https://youtu.be/ZJEo1w4oE8o  .

The opening shot is particularly blurred. There aren’t sharp images till 1’ in.

I could put the original render in Google Drive??

Other export settings haven't helped.

All the best

Comment: The main issue in the first shot is definitely over-compression. That image is completely full of moving detail, so youtube (or even the NLE) will have over-compress to meet its target bitrate. Compare that image full of grass to the next shot, where there are large patches of plain blue sky that barely move- a huge amount of data saved, which can be used to improve details in other areas of the image.

Comment: Another thing that can greatly affect compression artifacts is color- if there is a similar color tone/level to all of the detail, such as in low-light shots, even good compression is more likely to show visible artifacting.

Comment: Lastly, people sometimes suggest adding noise/grain to videos- this is sometimes bad advice because in theory the youtube compressor will waste bits trying to preserve the noise, ignoring "real" image details. However it could improve how detail is preserved in low-light or similar-color shots. If you've added noise, try removing it, or if you haven't, try adding it.

Comment: I don’t have noise/grain in my version of Resolve unfortunately. So there's nothing I can do to fix the 1st shot? A pity - I’ll need to replace it. And it sounds like there’s nothing more I can do to the ‘balloon woman’ shots either.
But thanks again Wiley.  I appreciate it!